# pyserial read() mixing bytes and regular character

Tags: python, pyserial

While reading values from UART air quality sensors, the byte array received is composed of both bytes and regular characters (letters). Indeed, it seems to automatically convert every ASCII character to ASCII format instead of kipping them as bytes.

For example, the supposed received line (tested with third party hardware):
b’\xff \x1d **\x2c** \x01 **\x43**’ (spaces added for clarity)
is received as:
b’\xff \x1d **,** \x01 **C**’ (spaces added for clarity)

Code below: (python 3.5)

```
import serial  
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate = 9600)  #useless part excluded, conection working  
ASK = b'\xff\x02\x13 ....... \x03'  
while True:  
    ser.write(ASK)  
    print(ser.read())
```

Working on a CM3 Lite module from Raspberry with Raspbian lite.

Comment: Had semiliar issue.
I found this helpfull:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728495/reading-hex-data-from-serial-port